# In a batch file how do I suppress output for a command that is inside FOR /F command

Tags: batch-file, stdout

Here is an example of a batch file fragment:

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=1" %%a in ('wmic process where "Caption = 'notepad++.exe'" get Processid ^| findstr /r "[0-9]"') do (
set procid=%%a
)

echo Notepad++ process ID is %procid%

pause
```

In it I get process ID for Notepad++ using `WMIC`, extract the actual number using `findstr` and then using `FOR /F` command to set the result as a variable for further use. Maybe not the most elegant way, but it works for me.

When Notepad++ is running and WIMC finds its process, this works perfectly fine and I get result like this:

```
Notepad++ process ID is 222648
Press any key to continue . . .
```

However if Notepad++ isn't running, result looks like this:

```
No Instance(s) Available.
Notepad++ process ID is
Press any key to continue . . .
```

This `No Instance(s) Available.` part is the message from WMIC and it's what bugs me. I would like it to not be printed on a screen.

When using command by itself in the Command Prompt I can suppress this message by adding `2>&1` at the end of WMIC part like this:

```
wmic process where "Caption = 'notepad++.exe'" get Processid 2>&1 | findstr /r "[0-9]"
```

However when I'm trying to do similar thing in a batch file like this:

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=1" %%a in ('wmic process where "Caption = 'notepad++.exe'" get Processid 2>&1 ^| findstr /r "[0-9]"') do (
set procid=%%a
)

echo Notepad++ process ID is %procid%

pause
```

Batch file just crashes.

What am I doing wrong here? What will de the right way to suppress WMIC output in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: Well you knew enough to escape the `^|`.  You also need to escape the `>` and `&`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Squashman, it worked!

Comment: And to improve the method, change `2>&1` to `2^>NUL`. It is more practical not to pass an error message to `findstr` than to allow it to filter it out afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Squashman and @Compo suggestions I was able to fix the crash and tidy up the whole thing a little bit. The final variant for now is as follows:

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic process where "Caption = 'notepad++.exe'" get Processid /value 2^>NUL') do (
set procid=%%a
)

echo Notepad++ process ID is %procid%

pause
```

`2>&1` have been changed to `2^>NUL` (`>` is escaped by `^`), also thanks to the `/value` switch for `WMIC` its output now can be parsed directly by `FOR /F` without need for `findstr`

Comment: Please see my comment under your question.

Comment: And you would not need the FINDSTR command if you would use the `/value` option with the `WMIC` command.

Comment: Thanks again @Squashman, that was great suggestion